# Find an equation for v as a function of x. If $v(t)= 12t^2 - 1$ and $x(t)= 2t + 5$

Tags: functions

If $v(t)= 12t^2 - 1$ and $x(t)= 2t + 5 $
find an equation for v as a function of x.

I can find a function for a geometric shape, like area as a function of perimeter for a square $A=(P/4)^2$ I don't know how to do one where there is no simple geometry.

I looked for similiar questions elsewhere but they all involved finding a function from a simple shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to solve $x=2t+5$ for $t$, then plug that expression into the equation for $y$.  It will give you an equation for $y$ that has $x$ on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

$$t=\frac{x-5}{2}$$
$$v(t)=12t^2-1\to v_1(x)=3(x-5)^2-1=3x^2-30x+74$$